# Get text via XPath, ignoring markup

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I have to retrieve text inside an HTML table, in the cells the text sometimes is inside a `<div>` and sometimes is not.

How can I make a `div` in a XPath optional?

My actual code:

`stuff = tree.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/text()")`

Wanted pseudocode:

`stuff = tree.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div or nothing/text()")`

Comment: `normalize-space(/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[5])`

Answer (score 1):

You want the [*string value*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the `td[5]` element.  Use **[`string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string)**:

```
stuff = tree.xpath("string(/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[5])")
```

This will return text without markup beneath `td[5]`.

You can also indirectly obtain the string value of an element via **[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)** as [suggested by splash58 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535209/we-scrape-xpath-python-lxml-middle-tag-or-not#comment56812626_34535209), if you also want whitespace to be trimmed on the ends and reduced interiorly.